# Comment out lines in JMeter HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter, comments

I try to comment out lines in `HTTP Sampler` with following code, but these lines appears in raw request too.

> /** * Commented line */

Is it possible to use block comments, like in a programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not exactly what you want but [HTTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) as other element have Comments field where you can paste your comments.

Also you can duplicate HTTP Sampler with comments and Disable it

Also you can add comments to its Label so you can see it in listeners.

Code comments can be added inside [JSR223 elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which actually execute code, for example:

```
/**
 Comments
 */

 //Comment
 log.info("Ignoring comments");
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, but you can use the comment section as the below image to add any comments to the HTTP samplers.

[image]